# Drools Eclipse Plugin ignores source level

Tags: eclipse, drools, jboss-tools

I have installed the Drools Eclipse Plugin `org.drools.eclipse` 7.36.0.Final into my Eclipse 2020_03 running with a Oracle JDK 1.8.0_92. I have downloaded und unzipped `drools-distribution-7.36.0.Final` and added the `binaries/` directory as `Drools > Installed Drools Runtimes` in the Eclipse Preferences.

As soon as I use any Java 1.5+ features (generics, foreach loops, closures, ...) I get error markers in the Rule Editor saying that there are syntax errors and those features require source level 1.5 (1.8 for closures).

My .drl files and the project itself seem to be fine, because I can compile and run via maven without errors. So it's not a blocking issue, but it's annoying that I cannot seem to get syntax checks for .drl files working properly in my IDE.

I have searched the internet and tried out all kinds of things:

- I have set the JDT source levels in my project and workspace to 1.8
- I have checked Installed JREs in the properties and only the one JDK 1.8.0_92 is listed
- I have created a `kmodule.xml` file in `/src/main/resources/META-INF/` with this content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kmodule xmlns="http://jboss.org/kie/6.0.0/kmodule">
    <configuration>
        <property key="drools.dialect.java.compiler.lnglevel" value="1.8" />
        <property key="drools.dialect.java.compiler" value="ECLIPSE" />
        <property key="drools.compiler.lnglevel" value="1.8" />
    </configuration>
    <kbase name="rules">
        <ksession name="codegen-rules"/>
    </kbase>
</kmodule>
```

- I have created a `kie.properties.conf` file in `/src/main/resources/META-INF/` with this content:

```
drools.dialect.java.compiler.lnglevel=1.8
drools.dialect.java.compiler=ECLIPSE
drools.compiler.lnglevel=1.8
```

- I have added the properties in the VM args section of my `eclipse.ini` file:

```
-Ddrools.dialect.java.compiler.lnglevel=1.8
-Ddrools.dialect.java.compiler=ECLIPSE
-Ddrools.compiler.lnglevel=1.8
```

But all of these do not seem to have any effect and it keeps giving me the same error markers.

How can I tell the *Rule Editor* that I want to enable Java 1.8 source level when syntax checking my `.drl` files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have run into this issue as well using the latest eclipse release and the latest drools release.

Using `Eclipse 2019-03` and the `Jboss Tools Integration Stack` [here](https://tools.jboss.org/downloads/jbosstools_is/2019-03/4.11.0.Final.html) does work. So either something broke in later eclipse releases or in the later drools versions. The integration stack uses 7.21.0.Final

I have not dug into what exactly broke but even if I did I don't know who I would report it to :(

Comment: Indeed. Thank you very much! 
I downgraded the Drools Eclipse Plugin to 7.21.0.Final and that works.

Comment: I have filed an issue at the Drools Project Issue Tracker: https://issues.redhat.com/browse/DROOLS-5388